# SQLAlchemy - SQL statement keeps running after closing session

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I have a python script to truncate a table on SQL Server. Here is the code:

```
# 2. Create connection 
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL,create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import text 
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

connection_url = URL.create(
    "mssql+pyodbc",
    # username="",
    # password="",
    host="SERVER NAME",
    # port=,
    database="DB NAME",
    query={
        "driver": "SQL Server Native Client 11.0",
        "TrustServerCertificate": "yes",
        # "authentication": "ActiveDirectoryIntegrated",
    },
)


# 4. Truncate table
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
try:
        session.execute(text('''TRUNCATE TABLE  [dbo].[MyTable]'''))
        session.commit()
except Exception as e:
        print("an error occured:", e)
finally:
        session.close()
```

The code seems to work but when I run `sp_whoisactive` on the SQL database, I see that 3+ hours later the query is still running.  I don't understand why is it still running even after I've closed the session?

Here is a screenshot from that result. I had two Truncate statements. :
[image]

Comment: It's recommended to use `try:`/`finally:` with `sessionmaker` so that `session.close()` gets called even in the presence of database errors. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: Thank for that. I have updated my code and question, but it's still not working. The only thing that seems to be working is to shut down the python kernel.

Comment: Do the queries stick around after the script is finished only in the case that there was an error, or do they stay around regardless until the kernel is shut down?

Comment: no it sticks around regardless of error or no error. only goes away if I shut down the kernel. I was told my IT that they don't think it's actually using up any resources.